# How do i change a value in mysql after set time

Tags: mysql

How can i using 1 line add a value and make it reset after a set time like 24 hours

I know this is bad question but i cant find any solution or help anywhere online and im sick of setting a timer and doing it manually :(

Comment: Maybe [this is what you are looking for](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is way to confusing.

Comment: _How can i using 1 line add a value and make it reset after a set time like 24 hours_ **You can't**